# Is there a reference for the commit from other branch that caused a conflict?

Tags: git

If I'm at a conflict while rebasing, what's the quickest way to know the SHA of the commit from other branch that caused the conflict. I.e. what was the last commit that was cherry-picked and failed?

I know I can manually figure out what commit it was, and `git rebase` tells you the subject line of the commit that's being applied etc., but I'm looking for something that's scriptable.

`MERGE_HEAD` doesn't mean anything upon a rebase conflict, and `REBASE_HEAD` (or anything similar) doesn't exist.

Comment: If (this is a fairly big if) you are doing rebase via repeated cherry-pick, as is true for interactive rebase or rebase done with `-m`, the information is directly available in `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`.  Otherwise see LeGEC's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think git keeps its work files in `.git/rebase-apply/`

Comment: It is, but the exact location and name of that file varies depending on Git version and whether you are using a secondary (`git worktree add`-ed) work-tree.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SHA of the commit that's currently causing a conflict during a rebase is in the file `.git/rebase-apply/original-commit`.